# Issue with Ant build file

Tags: java, ant, jar

I have a java file with the name test1.java with a simplle hello world message.

I have an ANT build script for the creation of the jar file as foll:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<project name="test1" default="main">

<target name="main" depends="compile, compress">
<echo>
    Building the .jar file
</echo>
</target>

<target name="compile">
    <javac srcdir="." includeantruntime="false"/>
</target>

<target name="compress">
    <jar jarfile="proj.jar" basedir="." includes="*.class">
            <manifest>
                <attribute name="Main-Class" value="test1"/>
            </manifest>
        </jar>

</target>


</project>
```

The file is successfully compiled and a ajar file is created.

But when i try to execute the jar as `java -jar proj.jar` I am getting the foll error:
**Invalid or corrupt jarfile proj.jar**

How can I resolve this issue.

The manifest file's contents are as foll:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.9.0
Created-By: pap64dev-20071008 (SR6) (IBM Corporation)
Main-Class: test1
```

Comment: If I unjar the jar created I see the class file named test1.class

Comment: Is a package declared in your class? Can you show the content of your class?

Comment: No I don't have a package declaration.Its just a simple java class

Answer (score 1):

Solved it by downgrading to Ant 1.8.4. Ant 1.9 seems to not work with Java 5

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest making the "compress" task depend on the "compile" task, because if "compress" is executed first there will be no class file to package.

Also are your sure the name of your main class is really "test1" (by convention class names should start with an uppercase letter).

Comment: I added the depends for the compress task.And after the ant job is rn I see the class which is generated to be `test1.class`

Comment: Ok, so do you still have the exact same problem when running the jar?

Comment: can you change the extension of the file from .jar to .zip, open it, and list the arborescence of files inside?

Comment: I unjared the proj.jar, It had test1.class and the META-INF directory.I have updated the contents of the manifest file in the question.Do you still want me to change the extention of the file to .zip from .jar.

Comment: dunno, works for me, as is with plain vanilla hello world class.

Comment: Here when I create by hand by not using ant it works and the **Created-By** has the value **1.5.0 (IBM Corporation)** .Can this be the real issue.How can I correct this via ant.

Comment: Solved it by downgrading to Ant 1.8.4. Ant 1.9 seems to not work with Java 5